# @use does not compile sass using node-sass, everything is in sass directory, using @import everything works

Tags: css, sass

I cannot seem to find anyone else having this problem with the @use rule, what am I doing wrong?
Using @import produces expected css, using @use there are no errors but the resulting file is not the expected css... below is a simplified version of the issue,
// lists.sass
ul, ol
text-align: left

```
  & &
    padding:
      bottom: 0
      left: 0

// code.sass
code
  padding: .25em
  line-height: 0

// main.sass
@use 'code'
@use 'lists'

// main.css
// producing exactly...
@use 'code' {}@use 'lists' {}

// main.css
// should produce...
code {
  padding: .25em;
  line-height: 0;
}

ul, ol {
  text-align: left;
}
ul ul, ol ol {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

if I try @use to @include @mixin I get error "no mixin {mixin name} found", if I add the namespace corner.rounded I get the error  "Invalid CSS after "  @include corners": expected "}", was ".rounded;""

```
// corners.sass
$radius: 3px

@mixin rounded
  border-radius: $radius

// main.sass
@use "corners"

.button
  @include rounded
  padding: 5px + $radius
```

using @import...

```
// main.sass
@import "corners"

.button
  @include rounded
  padding: 5px + $radius
```

produces expected css...

```
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px; }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because doing a Google search would have given the answer - and compiler support is in the docs for `@use`

Answer (score 1):

`@use` is only [supported](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) by `dart-sass`. As you are using *node-sass* this doesn't work for you. You have to use `@import` instead.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Gh05d (I marked his answer as useful) I found the documentation and installed "dart".
npm install --save-dev sass
and added a command to my package.json file:
"dart_build_css": "sass sass/main.sass stylesheets/main.css",
I used these sass source file test:

```
// corners.sass
$radius: 3px

@mixin rounded
  border-radius: $radius

// main.sass
@use "corners"

.button
  @include corners.rounded
  padding: 5px + corners.$radius
```

and got the expected css output:

```
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```